# unsupported Type RangeIndex for pandas.DataFrame.to_timestamp()

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I want to convert pandas timestamp like object to timestamp.
Here is the data I have

```
csv['ts']

0          2020-03-09 00:00:00
1          2020-03-09 00:00:02
2          2020-03-09 00:00:04
3          2020-03-09 00:00:06
4          2020-03-09 00:00:08
                  ...         
9926077    2022-01-09 22:54:32
9926078    2022-01-09 22:54:34
9926079    2022-01-09 22:54:36
9926080    2022-01-09 22:54:38
9926081    2022-01-09 22:54:40
Name: ts, Length: 9926082, dtype: object
```

However, I could not convert this data to timestampe by to_timestamp()

```
csv['ts'].to_timestamp()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
.py in <module>
----> 1 csv['ts'].to_timestamp()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in to_timestamp(self, freq, how, copy)
   5342 
   5343         if not isinstance(self.index, PeriodIndex):
-> 5344             raise TypeError(f"unsupported Type {type(self.index).__name__}")
   5345         new_index = self.index.to_timestamp(freq=freq, how=how)
   5346         return self._constructor(new_values, index=new_index).__finalize__(

TypeError: unsupported Type RangeIndex
```

Neither can I do

> pd.DataFrame.to_timestamp()

Can help explain why this happens and what should do to convert this timestamp-like objects to the timestamp in pandas.